# Greatest Integer Function Equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Show that $[x] + [x + 1/2] =[2x]$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $[ \cdot ]$ denotes the Greatest Integer Function.

I am having trouble formally showing this. Intuitively I understand that when the fractional component of $x$ is at least $0.5$ it'll add $1$ to both sides. As of right now I have $2$ inequalities:

$[x] \leq x < [x] + 1$

$[x + \frac12] \leq x + \frac12 < [x + \frac12] + 1$

I tried adding them together to form $[x] + [x + \frac12] \leq 2x + \frac12 < [x] + [x + \frac12] + 2$ in an attempt to rewrite this into a form for the floor function of $[2x]$ but am having some trouble. Is this the right track?

Comment: Surely a **duplicate**

Comment: Consider both if the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $x-\lfloor x\rfloor = \{x\}$, is less than $1/2$ or otherwise.

Comment: You know the definition of greatest integer, right?  Consider the cases where x, x + 1/2, and 2x variously either are or are not an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hermite's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity)